# Presenting ViewControllers Modally

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, view, switch-statement

I am Making a word game and I need some help with the navigation. This game starts in a menu, from that menu you can click 'create game' which would open the 'GameViewController'. in this GameViewController you can submit a word when it's the right word There Pop ups a screen which is 'RightWordViewController' When it's wrong it pop ups 'WrongwordViewController' in both right and wrong there is a button which would go back to the game.

In the GameViewController there is also a menu button which works perfectly except for after you have submitted a word. If you would click the menu button in a GameViewController when you already had submitted a right or wrong word the menu button would bring me back to the right or wrong view controller. I Understand why this is happening,I just don't know how to fix it. I use dismissModalViewcontroller which shows me the view behind the current, and that is Right or Wrong Viewcontroller I need to fix this and hope someone can help me.

To go from menu to game

```
-(IBAction)switchview:(id)sender {
 GameViewController *game = [[GameViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:game animated:YES];
```

the menu button that goes from the GameViewcontroller to the main view (menu) (it dismiss the current screen so when I have submitted a word right or wrong those screens pop up and when I would click this button right or wrong would show up again.. what I don't want ofc.)

```
-(IBAction)switchback:(id)sender {[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

to go either right or wrong I use:

```
if ([labelsText.text isEqualToString: textview.text]){

RightWordViewController *Rightword = [[RightWordViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:RightWord animated:YES];
}

else
{  WrongWordViewController *Wrongword = [[WrongWordViewController alloc]     initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:WrongWord animated:YES];
}
```

And then for Going back to the game screen when Im in Right or Wrong view controller

```
-(IBAction)switchback3:(id)sender {
GameViewController *game = [[GameViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:game animated:YES];
```

I hope someone can give me some really clear explanation or some sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the switchback3: method you don't need to preset the viewcontroller again.. just dismiss the one thats in the front..

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

also, add a boolean in gameview controller to set a status to check whether to show/not show the right/wrong view.

Comment: Thank you, I tried this before but the problem is that when I would do it like this, then I return to the GameViewController but All the words would be still submitted, and the will not be a new random word (which I load in ViewDidLoad section)

Comment: I Don't know what you mean with boolean in gameviewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

Use 
-(IBAction)switchback3:(id)sender {
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Reset your submitted words before presenting the right/wrong view controller.If you are presenting a view and u need to go back,use dismissModalViewController.No need to present that view again.